# Contextual Links not appearing in Panels

Tags: 7, panels, navigation

I use panels to display almost every page on my website. I display content type article as a panel, configured from

```
structure->content type->article->manage display
```

The contextual link cogwheel is not appearing on the full content type display rendered through panels, whereas it is displayed on the teaser view, rendered on the site home page, also rendered through panels as a panel page. What might be causing the error? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score -2):

Please apply a patch from [Impossible to set attributes on Panels panes](https://drupal.org/node/2169571) on Drupal.org.

This is a patch to the module I believe will fix the problem you have.